# How do I embed a repl into a website in full screen?

Tags: web, iframe, github-pages, replit

I have some code inside of a replit that I would like to import inside of my (github pages) website. Is there any way I could embed the replit inside an iframe or some other means that would just have the output of the replit showing in full screen and no code/other junk around it? I know repl.run was taken down, but there has to be another way, right?

Answer (score 1):

To embed the repl you need to use an `iframe`. So the source of the iframe will be the following.
`Repl-URL?Parameters`

The `Repl-URL` needs to be replaced with the URL of the repl. The parameters must have `embed=true` and `?lite=true` is optional for light theme.

For example:

`<iframe frameborder="0" width="100%" height="500px" src="https://replit.com/@ritza/demo-embed?embed=true"></iframe>`